# Theorem headings and figures in the left margin

Tags: margins, theorems

Is there a way to replicate this style of theorem, definition, etc. headings, as well as figures in the left margin? I'd love if it played nice with the amsthm package so that I don't have to worry about entering the headings manually. Of course, the right margin would also have to be adjusted so that the text flows (almost) to the edge, to make up for the lost space on the left.

[image]

Comment: Not with an existing package, but it shouldn't be that hard to implement with \marginpar or paracol (depending on where the normal margins are.